# How can i use "DateTime" field in "DynamicQueryable" string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How can i use "`DateTime`" field in "`DynamicQueryable`" string?

ex:

```
strWhere += "Time >= (\"" + DateTime.Now + "\")";
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong it your code. That should work. You get unexpected result or something? What is your `strWhere` and what do you want as an output?

Comment: Is this query run in sql server?

Answer (score 0):

```
strWhere += "Time >= (\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\")";
```

or

```
strWhere += "Time >= (\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd\MMM\yyyy") + "\")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Could you please care to add some explanation to this one line answer?